# Android CustomListview, SQLIte Database,CustomAdpater

Tags: android, android-sqlite, listview-adapter

i am doing a shopping application, i have each row loaded in the listview and each row has a delete button. when i click the delete button i can get its position and id of the row. My problem is when i call a database function from the onclick function of the button in the customadapter class i get a nulpointerexception.

What i want is to remove the selected row from the database by passing the

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Product prod = data.get(pos);
    //String gt=prod.getProductName();
     prodid=prod.getId();
     prod.setId(prodid);

                   //passing id to database class gives NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION when opening database
               dcon.open(); 
               dcon.DoDeleteItem(prodid)

//just to show that button clicked  
Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked"+prodid+"::",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you are using a custom layout for the list view row, and you have created a custom adapter for the listview? If not, I recommend you do so.

What you can do then do is to set the tag of the delete button to the position or id of the cursor data representing the database. In your onclick method, you then cast the view back to your class of your delete button (it could be Button or it could be ImageButton depending on what you had used as the class for the delete button). Then read out the tag using and cast it back to an integer position or id. Now you can then call your database - specifically the delete function and pass in this position/id.

Comment: Hi Yaojin, thanks for the advice, BUT yes i have the custom adapter for the listview and thats where the onClick function for the delete button lies. Your explanation makes sense but i am having difficulties following it with the casts and all, is there some sample code that uses this that you can refer me to?